# Extending a class in C++ using header files

Tags: c++, class, header, superclass, extending

I found found out that to extend a class I would have to do this:

```
class x : public extendsThis { // rest here
};
```

So, I create 2 classes, in two seperate files:

```
- particle.h -
class particle : public program {
};

 - program.h -

 class program {
    particle* myParticle;
 };
```

However, in the program class I wanted to have particle objects, which then again extend the program class.

This would however require me to have a include program.h in the particle class, and a particle.h include in the program class to let them know about each other. This however created some infinite loop that made me unable to compile.

Is there any way around this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If a program has a program member variable with a program member variable with a program member variable and so on, you'll *never* be able to instantiate your class. I guess you could use a *pointer* to a particle (*isa program*), instead, as long as you don't initiate it in the constructor, but this still seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that, the line : "particle myParticle" should have been: "particle *myParticle"

Comment: @Ruddie Do not edit the question in a way that invalidates all existing answers!

Comment: Oh, well, I am sorry about that. Although after you comment - I found out I forgot that it was indeed a pointer.

Comment: @Ruddie Did any of these answers solve your problem?

Comment: @Chris, I found a workaround myself, I simply had my class structure wrong, causing this strange effect. Simply changing this all around a bit fixed my problem. It comes down to the fact that I did not really correctly see what the extension really does/where is should be used for (I figured this out now though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can work around this. You can make a very simple class declaration.

In program.h:

```
class particle;

class program
{
  particle *myParticle;
};
```

Keep in mind that you need to use a pointer to particle.

Comment: By the way, I think you should consider why you need to do this. Perhaps you can avoid this strange inter-dependency.

Comment: Don't you also have to make sure that the particle's constructor is not called by the program's constructor?

Comment: @Chris No, you don't. In fact, given the above "design", particle's constructor almost certainly SHOULD be called by program's constructor, if it had one.

Comment: @Neil Oh, right, sorry. The program's constructor can call the particle's constructor as long as the latter does not then assign its *own* `myParticle` member variable to a `new particle`. This is still really weird, though.

Comment: @Neil I posted an answer with sample code that illustrates what I *meant* to say

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can use a forward declaration in one of the include files:

```
class a;

class b { a* ptr; };
```

It can also be an indication your design may need to be re-thought. Generally your program should "know" about it's components but not the reverse. The components of the program should be small stand alone classes with a simple well defined function. If you entangle all the classes you get "spooky action at a distance" (bugs). ;)

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Although I simply wanted the class 'program' to hold my SDL_Surfaces (which are simply images). And these could be used in the particle class (which I found usefull), although I could also simply pass these from the program class to the particle class. Would this be a more viable option?

Comment: That sounds like a "cleaner" option. Then the classes aren't dependent on each other

Answer (score 0):

It may just be me, but it seems like you're doing this wrong. Why would you want to extend the particle class with the program class? It theory you'd get something like this:

```
class particle {
    particle *myParticle;
};
```

Notice how extending the class could potentially create an infinite loop? I mean, this is just my understanding and I could be horribly wrong, but it's something to consider. Someone let me know if I'm waaaay off here.

Comment: You are way off here. The OP needs a pointer to the particle in his program, not an instance.

Comment: I know, I was just putting down what he had when I answered. Looks like he changed it, so will I :) Otherwise, though, is it doing about what I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer to explain what I meant by the dangers of calling the default particle constructor from the default program constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class particle;

class program {
    particle* myParticle;

public:
    program();
};

class particle : public program {
public:
    particle()
    {
        std::cout << "Particle constructor\n" << std::flush;
    }
};

program::program()
{
    std::cout << "Program constructor\n" << std::flush;
    myParticle = new particle();
}

int main()
{
    program *myProgram = new program();
    delete myProgram;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this program, it continues to print "Program constructor" because `particle::particle()` always calls `program::program()` first, resulting in an infinite loop. Commenting out the line `myParticle = new particle();` fixes this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use include guards in your header files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard